# How do you create this regex to block character?

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I need to create something specific with some logic, but I can not determine this regex ...

**There are two types of regex, which are:**

**1) Check the string if there is a "dot" already typed, if there is a second point, regardless of its location, it can not be typed.**

**2) Block these characters, regardless of location, the char are:**!@#$%¨&*()_-+={}[]:;<>"|\'

**My failed attempts**

```
     this._filterData.addEventListener('keyup', (_event: KeyboardEvent) => {


           console.log(/^[.]+$/.test(this._filterData.value))


        });

        this._filterData.addEventListener('keypress', (_event: KeyboardEvent) => {
            const KEYBOARD_KEY = _event.key;

            console.log(/^[!@#$%&*()_-+={}[\]:;<>|\\"']+$/.test(this._filterData.value))
});
```

Comment: Please share a fiddle (e.g. use jsfiddle.net). It is not clear what does not work for you: the regexps or the code.

Answer (score 0):

`/^[.]+$/` checks for a dot at the start of the string, that continues till the end of the string. `/\./` would return true if there is any dot in the string.

```js
/^[.]+$/.test('.....'); // true
/^[.]+$/.test('some . in the sentence'); // false
/\./.test('.....'); // true
/\./.test('some . in the sentence'); // true
```

Same goes for `/^[!@#$%&*()_-+={}[\]:;<>|\\"']+$/`. This only works if the string only cosists out of these characters from start to end. `/[!@#$%&*()_\-+={}[\]:;<>|\\"']/` would match any of the characters anywhere inside the string.

If you want to check if the string contains the character somewhere in the string, use `/\./` and `/[!@#$%&*()_\-+={}[\]:;<>|\\"']/`. These will match the tokens as long as they're somewhere in the string.

Comment: And which regex would I use for each case? Add this to your reply and I'll give you punctuation!

Answer (score 0):

To solve for the #1 case, the easiest way I could find was to test for any character followed by a dot followed by any number of characters followed by a dot, like so:

```
.\..*\.
```

and then fail your input if that test passes. E.g.:

```
if (/.\..*\./.test(this._filterData.value)) { return false; }
```

To prevent your forbidden characters (the #2 case), create a character class of all your forbidden characters, like so (note which characters needed escaping):

```
/[!@#\$%¨&\*\(\)_\-\+={}\[\]:;<>"\|\\']/
```

and then (similar to #1 above) fail your input when that regex test passes.

For future regex endeavors, I recommend an online regex playground. I used https://regex101.com (taking care to choose the correct regex flavor). For further regex reference, I've found https://www.regular-expressions.info/ to be very helpful.